# Is the 'Chern number' of a topological Kondo insulator an integer?

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-insulators, topological-phase

If you calculate the anomalous Hall conductance $\sigma_{xy}/\sigma_0$ for a simple complex hopping model at a whole band filling, this will equal an integer Chern number (given e=h=1).

I would like to know if one calculated $\sigma_{xy}/\sigma_0$ in a topological Kondo insulator if they should expect an integer as well?